# c# asp.net report and sub report in report viewer (or reportviewer)

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, report-viewer2010, reportviewer2008

I did all the steps from this waltrought:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/01/03/walkthrough-add-a-subreport-in-local-report-in-reportviewer.aspx

and when i run it i get the first father report and instead the sub
report i get:

> Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'Subreport5',
>   located at: C:...

i attach a print screen file 
[image: (the subreport error)]

i am using VS2010 framework 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run the subreport by itself, given the right parameters?  If you can't, your problem is that.

If you can run it successfully by itself, double-check that you are passing the parameters correctly to your subreport.  Make sure the parameter types match and that you are passing all of them.

Another problem might be that -- if I recall correctly -- when you have a subreport in a local report, you need to provide the data for the subreport programmatically, just as you do with the parent report.  There's an event that's raised - SubreportProcessingEvent -- when the subreport is being processed.  You write a handler for that event and supply data in the handler.  Here's some more information about it:  [LocalReport.SubReportProcessingEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.subreportprocessing%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  There's a good example on that page.